# MergePropertyDescriptor clones value whereas standard property descriptor does not

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

We have a set up in which a property grid is used to set properties on certain given class. Some of those properties are references to other classes which we want to set by reference.
For those properties a proper `UITypeEditor` is set and it works when using the property grid with one source class.

As we are able to select multiple classes and set properties to them we realized an issue.
When selecting several classes and editing a property the `PropertyDescriptor` passed into our `CustomUITypeEditor.EditValue` is an internal class called `MergePropertyDescriptor`.

Unfortunately the `SetValue` of this Descriptor has a call to `CopyValue` with this code:

```
private object CopyValue(object value)
{
  if (value == null)
    return value;
  Type type = value.GetType();
  if (type.IsValueType)
    return value;
  object obj1 = (object) null;
  ICloneable cloneable = value as ICloneable;
  if (cloneable != null)
    obj1 = cloneable.Clone();  // <!---------------------- class is cloned!

...
```

where the `ICloneable` interface is called for those classes. The classes in question have clone interfaces for other purposes. To maintain the link-consistency when setting one class as reference for an other this interface **must** not be used.

I can't think of a proper way to ensure that whether selecting one or several classes guarantees that the classes are not deep copied.